# Moving cartographic representation of labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, representation

Cartographic representation in ArcMap is a nice way to temporary change geometry of features, so you can make adjustments just for map making.

In my mapping project I need to move some point features with representations and also, I need to automatically label them. It seems that labels are always positioned in relation to the original geometry, not where the representation was moved.

[image]

Is this how representations are supposed to work or is there a way to automatically label representations?

Comment: Maybe for you Annotations are an alternative to Lables? You can move Annotations individual.

Comment: If there is no alternative I'll have to use annotations.

Comment: Do you have the Maplex Extension you can create much better labeling and then convert to annotation preserving the placement.

Comment: Yes I do. I have ArcGIS 10. But Maplex doesn't solve the problem. It puts the label where the original geometry is, not where the representation is. In this case it behaves just like the standard labeling engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer. The problem described above occurs only if you use the "move tool" from the representation toolbar.

It seems that you have to use the "select tool" (black arrow with "R" in the lower-right corner icon) to move representations if you want the label to fallow.

Comment: ahhh, thanks for this! Have been stumbling around this for awhile. (BTW, it's okay to mark your own answer as correct)