# Label point according to cartographic representation position instead of geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, labeling, representation

I have set up a cartographic representation on a point feature class, which simply offsets the point. I would like to label the point at the representation, not at its physical location. I had a look at [Moving cartographic representation of labels in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55459/arcmap-cartographic-representation-and-labels) but I am not editing the representations at all.

[image]

The purple points show the physical location, with the purple labels at default settings. The black points are the representations which have been offset, while the black labels show where I would like the labels to be.

Currently, I am showing the black labels on a different copy of the layer, with symbology turned off and the labels offset through Maplex. Is there a way to link the label placement with the cartographic representation, and not the physical features?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (possibly laziest) way to do that would be to keep the two shapefiles active but have the black symbols be invisible and change the color of the text labels to the same as that of the purple layer, and disactivating the label symbology on the purple shapefile.

Comment: I'm actually looking to link the purple labels (currently attached to the physical locations of the purple features) with the placement of the black cartographic representations of the purple features.